# pass values to parent element react hooks

Tags: reactjs

Hope you can clarify this issue:

**I have parent component:**

````
function App() {


const [ thanks, setThanks ] = useState(null);


const thankerHandler=(value)=>{
  setThanks(value)
}
**//in the return**
<Route component={PaymentPage} thankerHandler={thankerHandler} path="/payment" />```
````

**and the child component :**

```
 const PaymentPage=({thankerHandler})=> {
const [thanks, setThanks] = useState(false);
**//after some logic**
useEffect(() => {
     
    thankerHandler(thanks);

}, [thanks])
```

the problem is that react is telling me the following:

```
     61 | useEffect(() => {
  62 |      
> 63 |     thankerHandler(thanks);
  64 | 
  65 | }, [thanks])

thankerHandler is not a function
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong here, the idea is that when the function will be called in the child component, it will update the value in the parent, but it is not doing the thing, when I console log thankerHandler, just gives me the value of undefined because of the null state in the parent, if I set it there to false, gives me false and so on, but it does not recongnices it as a function.

anyone knows what I am doing wrong here?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `PaymentPage` component is rendered via `Route` component, `props` passed to `Route` component are not passed to the `PaymentPage` component.

Instead of using `component` prop to render the `PaymentPage` component, use `render` prop which takes a function. It will allow you to pass the `props` to `PaymentPage` component

Change

```
<Route component={PaymentPage} thankerHandler={thankerHandler} path="/payment" />
```

to

```
<Route
  path="/payment"
  render={(routerProps) => <PaymentPage {...routerProps} thankerHandler={thankerHandler} />}
/>
```

Apart from this problem, there is another problem in `PaymentPage` component.

Since `useEffect` is calling the `thankerHandler` function, `thankerHandler` should be added to the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook

```
useEffect(() => {
   thankerHandler(thanks);
}, [thanks, thankerHandler]);
```

but adding `thankerHandler` to the dependency array of `useEffect` hook will cause another problem, i.e. when `App` component re-renders, `thankerHandler` function will be re-created and the reference to this new function will be passed to `PaymentPage` component which will cause the `useEffect` hook in `PaymentPage` component to run again. This may or may not be something you want. If you don't want this, make sure to wrap `thankerHanlder` function in `useCallback` hook to prevent `useEffect` hook from running unnecessarily.

Comment: thank you very much Yousaf, you saved my day, do you know where can i find more information about this issue? I was goggleing in every possible way but never worked out. Bassically as a rockie that I am I would appreciate whatever resource you can recomend, thank you very much :)

Comment: If you want to learn more about react router, you can visit [react router docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) and if you want to lean anything about react, [react docs](https://reactjs.org/) are the best place.

Answer (score 0):

try to use render method in `Route` component:

```
<Route render={() => <PaymentPage thankerHandler={thankerHandler} />} path="/payment" />
```